# How to extract day,month,year from a filled cell dynamically new cell we're added as row in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to work following things in excel
I have
Column

```
A.            B.         C.       D
12/12/17.     12.       Dec.      17
13/12/17.     13.       Dec       17
```

From column A how to extract date and month and year as shown in column B,C,D?

if any of them entering 3rd and 4 th row on their own, for row 3 and 4 column B,C,D needs to be updated automatically.

```
Row 3 column A is 14/12/17
Row 4 column A is 15/12/17
```

Note : not to use fill option in column B,C,D

Comment: I mentioned in note that not to use the fill option.

Answer (score 1):

Day

```
=Day(A1)
```

Month

```
=TEXT(A1,"ddd")
```

Year:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"yy")
```

[image]